# Rails simple form gives InvalidAuthenticityToken error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, token

I have a simple form like this:

```
<form name="serachForm" method="post" action="/home/search">   
  <input type="text" name="searchText" size="15" value="">
  <input class="image" name="searchsubmit" value="Busca" src="/images/btn_go_search.gif" align="top" border="0" height="17" type="image" width="29">
</form>
```

And a controller with this method:

```
  def busca
    puts params[:searchText]
  end
```

When I do a click on the image button in the form I get a ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken. here's the full StackTrace:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/request_forgery_protection.rb:86:in
>   `verify_authenticity_token'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in`
>   send'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in
>   `evaluate_method'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`
>   call'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:225:in
>   `call'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:629:in`
>   run_before_filters'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:615:in
>   `call_filters'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in`
>   perform_action_without_benchmark'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in
>   `perform_action_without_rescue'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in`
>   perform_action_without_rescue'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:136:in
>   `perform_action_without_caching'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/caching/sql_cache.rb:13:in`perform_action'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in
>   `cache'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:8:in`
>   cache'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/caching/sql_cache.rb:12:in `perform_action'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in`
>   send'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:524:in
>   `process_without_filters'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in`
>   process_without_session_management_support'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/session_management.rb:134:in
>   `process'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:392:in`
>   process'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/webrick_server.rb:74:in
>   `service'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/servers/webrick.rb:66 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in`
>   require'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in
>   `new_constants_in'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:153:in`
>   require'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/server.rb:49

What is happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, all non-GET actions requires the authenticity token to be passed along with the request. Rails uses the authenticity token to avoid CSRF attacks.

The easiest way to ensure that it is always in place, is to use the `form_tag` helper instead of writing the HTML by hand.

```
<% form_tag "/home/search", :name => "searchForm" do %>
  fields here
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 24):

Along the lines of Nat, adding

```
<%= token_tag %>
```

just after the HTML "form" tag works

Comment: Thank you! This should be added to the accepted answer.

Comment: <=% token_tag nil %> should be used

Answer (score 7):

If you don't use helpers to generate your form tags, this is how you manually generate the hidden field with the authenticity token:

```
<input type="hidden" 
       value="<%= form_authenticity_token() %>" 
       name="authenticity_token"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a form helper as others have suggested above will work.

Since this is a search form though, the method should actually be 'get'.  In general, you should use a 'get' unless something in the database is going to change.

Using method='get' for search forms is more bookmark/back button friendly as well.