# How to pass user.id from one controller to another "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, stripe-payments

So I'm building an e-commerce platform that processes payments via Stripe. Once this has been successfully processed I want to create an Order entry for page admins to see on an Orders page.

Stripe successfully processes payment, Then Order is created by adding an entry that captures:

- @product.id
- @user.id
- @product.price

Product and Price are being pulled successfully, but unfortunately @user.id isn't being pulled into the record. I get the following error :
"undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass".

** Payments Controller **

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    token = params[:stripeToken]
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @user = current_user
    # Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    begin
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => (@product.price*100).to_i, # amount in cents, again
        :currency => "usd",
        :source => token,
        :description => params[:stripeEmail]
      )

      if charge.paid
        Order.create!(          
          product_id: @product.id, 
          user_id: @user_id, 
          total: @product.price)
      end

      flash[:success] = "Payment processed successfully"
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e 
      #Card was declined
      body = e.json_body
      err = body[:error]
      flash[:error] = "Unfortunately, there was an error processing your payment: #{err[:message]}"
    end
    redirect_to product_path(@product)
  end
end
```

** orders Controller**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  def index
  end

  def show 
  end

  def create
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

** Show page where I am rendering the payments partial (via Stripe)**

```
<div class="col-md-6 center text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-spacing">
      <%= image_tag(@product.image_url, class:" img-responsive center") %>
    </div>

    <h2>
      <%= @product.name %>
    </h2>

    <h4>
      <%= @product.desc %>
      <%= @product.style %>
      <strong>$<%= '%.2f' % @product.price %></strong>
    </h4>

    <%= form_tag("/payments/create", remote: true) do %>
      <%= render partial: "shared/stripe_checkout_button" %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:product_id, @product.id) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

** My OrdersController **

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  # before_filter :authenticate_user!
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  def index
  end

  def show 
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.create(order_params)
    respond_with @order
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:product_id, :user_id, :total)
  end
end
```

Now I've already considered adding:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:user_id, @user.id) %>
```

But I get the exact same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

It turned out the AJAX request I was making didn't carry the CSRF token. For that reason, Rails was killing my session. I added skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token in my paymentsController and all is well now.

But I would still like to know how to fix/why this is happening, if anyone has any info

**UPDATE 2**

Now that I understand the problem better, I've found an older post dealing with the issue, might be helpful to others.

[Rails simple form gives InvalidAuthenticityToken error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383997/rails-simple-form-gives-invalidauthenticitytoken-error?rq=1)

Comment: you have: `product_id: @product.id` but `user_id: @user_id` have you tried `user_id: @user.id` ? also - have you checked that `@user` is actually populated properly before calling `id` on it?

Comment: check update in description. 
also thanks to your comment I got lead to this link which gave me the updated workaround.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423718/rails-devise-current-user-is-nil

Comment: ok, so your `@user` is empty... this means that this line: `@user = current_user` isn't working the way you think it is (right because it's the only place where `@user` is being populated` to check, you can temporarily add something like: `raise @user.inspect` and your app will raise an exception with the value you have in `@user` and then you'll know for sure.

Comment: You really don't want to skip authenticity token... (that's like removing login because it's easier... it just removes the safety check you really want left in). you want to fix it so that it gets the proper authenticity token.

Comment: Probably you should look at removing the `form_tag` in figuring out how to do a proper `form_for`... that will fix your auth-token woes. If you haven't done so yet, you should read every single one of the Rails Guides... but specific to your situation, you need to look at the one on form-helpers: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html (and read well beyond the "basic form" because very few people use that one regularly)

Comment: you're totally right. form_for is far more appropriate for any sort of model input.

Comment: I've had a look at the form_for documentation. Correct me if I'm wrong but wether you're using a form_tag or a form_for, neither generates CSRF tokens unless explicitly told to.

form_for is more applicable when dealing with a specific model while form_tag is more suitable for generic data such as mailer forms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially form_tag's do not automatically generate CSRF tokens, unless explicitly told to do so, however neither do form_for tag's, as they chopped that in [Rails 4](https://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-4-whats-new/).

I simply resolved the issue by adding a hidden input in my form:

```
<%= form_tag("/payments/create", remote: true) do %>
   <%= render partial: "shared/stripe_checkout_button" %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag(:product_id, @product.id) %>
   <input type="hidden" value="<%= form_authenticity_token() %>"name="authenticity_token"/>
<% end %>
```

The main reason they chopped automatic generation of CSRF tokens has to do with people fragment-caching because the authenticity token would be wrong on subsequent requests when the form was pulled from the cache.